# Where can I see the last mount time?

Tags: filesystems, ext3, fat

E.g: I need to know when was the last time a pendrive was mounted. Where could I see that? The pendrive has e.g.: FAT32, EXT3 filesystem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ext3 stores the last mount time and can be retrieved with:

```
dumpe2fs -h /dev/node
```

I'm not sure that FAT stores this information.

Comment: dumpe2fs same as tune2fs can not retrieve mount time for NTFS and FAT filesystems.